# How can I instantiate a new ChromeDriver using a relative path in C#?

Tags: c#, path, selenium-webdriver, relative-path

It works using an absolute path like:

```
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\<my user>\Documents\<my project>\WebDrivers\Chrome\");
```

But since I run my tests on a TFS build server too, I need it to be a relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue:

1. Put the chromedriver.exe in a known path (easy way is to simply drag the file from Windows Explorer into Visual Studio)
2. Use this relative path syntax: `WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"../../");`

The key is to find the correct path where the driver lives with something like this:

`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

Answer (score 4):

Add the drivers into your solution and in the properties window, define that you want to copy the files to the output directory.

[File Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5F72.png)

In the picture above, the drivers are in the resources directory:

```
/my solution
   /resources
     /chromedriver.exe
     /IEDriverServer.exe
```

After a build, they will be copied to:

```
/bin
   /debug
      /resources
        /chromedriver.exe
        /IEDriverServer.exe
```

When you are creating your driver, you can define the path to the driver now relative in the bin directory.

```
return new ChromeDriver("resources");
```

Answer (score 2):

you may have enum for your all drivers:

```
  public enum Drivers
    {
        Chrome,
        Firefox,
        Safari,
        Edge,
        IE
    }


  public static IWebDriver GetDriver(Drivers driver)
        {
            var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            // below is my location where I copied all drivers like chromedriver.exe 
            var relativePath = @"..\..\bin\Debug\BrowserDriver"; 
            var chromeDriverPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(outPutDirectory,relativePath));
            // return this driver , just debug this code and check the "outPutDirectory" path
            return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in java :

```
System.setProperty(“webdriver.chrome.driver”,
      new File(“./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe”).getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: This is Java not C#!